# How to modify arrays of hashes in ruby 2.1.2?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, ruby-2.1

I have an array of hashes called `array_of_hash`:

```
array_of_hash = [
 {:name=>"1", :address=>"USA", :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB"},
 {:name=>"5", :address=>"UK", :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"BC"},
 {:name=>"6", :address=>"CANADA", :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"CD"},
 {:name=>"29", :address=>"GERMANY", :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"], :sequence=>"DE"},
 {:name=>"30", :address=>"CHINA", :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"], :sequence=>"FG"}
]
```

I wish to group these hashes by consecutive value of the key `:name`. The first group would be `"1"` alone since there is no key with `:name => "1".succ #=> "2"`. The second group would contain hashes with values of `"5"` and `"6"`. The third group would be the last two hashes in the array, for which `:name=>29` and `:name=>30`.

My desired array of hashes should look like this:

```
[
   {:name=>"1", :address=>"USA", :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB"},
   {:name=>"5-6", :address=>"UK,CANADA", :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"BC,CD"},
   {:name=>"29-30", :address=>"GERMANY,CHINA", :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"], :sequence=>"DE, FG"},
]
```

Use case II

```
array_of_hash = [
 {:name=>"1", :address=>"USA", :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB"},
 {:name=>"2", :address=>"UK", :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"BC"},
 {:name=>"3", :address=>"CANADA", :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"CD"},
 {:name=>"29", :address=>"GERMANY", :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"], :sequence=>"DE"},
 {:name=>"30", :address=>"CHINA", :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"], :sequence=>"FG"}
]
```

Desired result for use case II

```
[
   {:name=>"1-3", :address=>"USA,UK,CANADA", :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB,BC,CD"},
   {:name=>"29-30", :address=>"GERMANY,CHINA", :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"], :sequence=>"DE, FG"},
]
```

What I did so far:

```
new_array_of_hashes = []
new_array_of_hashes << { name: array_of_hashes.map {|h| h[:name].to_i}} << {address: array_of_hashes.map {|h| h[:address]}} << {collection: array_of_hashes.map {|h| h[:collection]}} << {sequence: array_of_hashes.map {|h| h[:sequence]}}

[{:name=>[1, 5, 6, 29, 30]},
 {:address=>["USA", "UK", "CANADA", "GERMANY", "CHINA"]},
 {:collection=>
[["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"],
["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"],
["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"],
["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"],
["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"]]},
 {:sequence=>["AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "FG"]}]
```

I am only able to combine it.

Comment: How do you determine which elements to combine and which to leave separate?

Comment: @moveson If the `:collection` value is same then combine

Comment: In that case, shouldn't the first three elements all be combined?

Comment: that's the most difficult part. if they are in sequence only they will be combined else they should be separated.

Comment: Don't use comments to display code. Instead, edit your question and add the information requested into the question as if it'd been there originally. Don't use "edit" or "update" tags to mark the changes. We can see what changed and when if we need to.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Your explanation of what should be joined doesn't make sense. 1, 5 and 6 have matching `:collection` arrays so they should all be combined but your example counters that.

Comment: Does "in sequence" mean when the `:name` values are consecutive?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 yes!

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry kind of new here. So trying to learn.

Comment: No need to be sorry (and don't use comments for thanks). Remember that SO isn't a "help me" site, it's a reference site to create articles of programming problems and their associated answers for others in the future. As such it means questions have to be complete so you have to do your research and write a detailed, complete question. If there is a lot of back and forth trying to figure it out then we'll close the question because it's broad or not defined or doesn't meet "[mcve]". https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263 is also important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's make an array of the groups that we ultimately want. We'll use Ruby's `Array#slice_when` method, which iterates over an array with the current and next array element, allowing us to compare the two. Our conditional will instruct Ruby to slice the array if the names (converted to integers) are not sequential or if the collections are not identical.

```
>> groups = array_of_hash.slice_when { |i, j| i[:name].to_i + 1 != j[:name].to_i || i[:collection] != j[:collection] }.to_a
```

But because you are using Ruby 2.1, you'll need to use `slice_before` and use local variables to keep track of previous elements. Per the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before), we can accomplish this by first priming a local variable:

```
>> prev = array_of_hash[0]
```

and then resetting it and a second local variable as we iterate over the array:

```
>> groups = array_of_hash.slice_before { |e| prev, prev2 = e, prev; prev2[:name].to_i + 1 != prev[:name].to_i || prev2[:collection] != prev[:collection] }.to_a
```

In either case, `groups` should now look like this:

```
=> [[{:name=>"1",
   :address=>"USA",
   :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"],
   :sequence=>"AB"}],
 [{:name=>"5",
   :address=>"UK",
   :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"],
   :sequence=>"BC"},
  {:name=>"6",
   :address=>"CANADA",
   :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"],
   :sequence=>"CD"}],
 [{:name=>"29",
   :address=>"GERMANY",
   :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"],
   :sequence=>"DE"},
  {:name=>"30",
   :address=>"CHINA",
   :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"],
   :sequence=>"FG"}]]
```

Now we take the resulting array and map its elements to a new hash, formatted as you specified.

For `:name`, we take the first and last elements of the group, call `.uniq` to eliminate duplicates, and join them with a hyphen. (If only one element exists, `join` returns the single element unchanged.)

For `:collection`, we simply use the collection found in the first element of the group.

For `:sequence`, we join the sequences of each element of the group with a comma. (Again, single elements are returned unchanged.)

```
>> groups.map { |group| {name: [group.first[:name], group.last[:name]].uniq.join('-'), 
                         collection: group.first[:collection], 
                         sequence: group.map { |e| e[:sequence] }.join(',') } }

=> [{:name=>"1",
  :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"],
  :sequence=>"AB"},
 {:name=>"5-6",
  :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"],
  :sequence=>"BC,CD"},
 {:name=>"29-30",
  :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"],
  :sequence=>"DE,FG"}]
```

Comment: Thank you but my ruby version is 2.1.2. `when_slice` only works in 2.2 i guess.

Comment: You have no way to upgrade? Ruby 2.1 is now 3+ years old. The code will be more involved without `slice_when`.

Comment: yes that's the problem i can't upgrade. Is there similar method like `when_slice` ?

Comment: It's messy, but you can do this with `slice_before`. See updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
def slice_when(array)
  big = []
  small = []
  last_index = array.size - 1
  (0..last_index).each do |i|
    small << array[i]
    if last_index == i || yield(array[i], array[i + 1])
      big << small
      small = []
    end
  end
  big
end
```

You can try using this, if you do not want to use `slice_before`. Keep in mind that it already returns an `Array`, not an `Enumurator`.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def aggregate(array_of_hash)
  array_of_hash.chunk_while { |g,h| h[:name] == g[:name].succ }.
    flat_map { |a| a.chunk { |g| g[:collection] }.map { |_c,b| combine(b) } }
end

def combine(arr)
  names     = values_for_key(arr, :name)
  addresses = values_for_key(arr, :address)
  sequences = values_for_key(arr, :sequence)
  arr.first.merge {
    name: names.size==1 ? names.first : "%s-%s" % [names.first, names[-1]],
    address:  addresses.join(','),
    sequence: sequences.join(',')
  }
end

def values_for_key(arr, key)
  arr.map { |h| h[key] }
end
```

**Example**

```
aggregate(array_of_hash)
  #=> [{:name=>"1", :address=>"USA",
  #     :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB"},
  #    {:name=>"5-6", :address=>"UK,CANADA",
  #     :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"BC,CD"},
  #    {:name=>"29-30", :address=>"GERMANY,CHINA",
  #     :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"], :sequence=>"DE,FG"}]
```

Here's second example.

```
array_of_hash[2][:collection] = ['dog', 'cat', 'pig']
  #=> [{:name=>"1", :address=>"USA",
  #     :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB"},
  #    {:name=>"5", :address=>"UK",
  #     :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"BC"},
  #    {:name=>"6", :address=>"CANADA",
  #     :collection=>["dog", "cat", "pig"], :sequence=>"CD"},
  #    {:name=>"29-30", :address=>"GERMANY,CHINA",
  #     :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"], :sequence=>"DE,FG"}]
```

In this example the hashes with `:name=>"5"` and `:name=>"6"` cannot be grouped because the values of `:collection` are different. The question does not state whether this could this situation could occur. If it could not the code is still correct, but it could be simplified to the following.

```
def aggregate(array_of_hash)
  array_of_hash.chunk_while { |g,h| h[:name] == g[:name].succ }.
    map { |a| combine(a) }
end
```

**Explanation**

For the example above the steps are as follows.

```
e0 = array_of_hash.chunk_while { |g,h| h[:name] == g[:name].succ }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fa25e022f30>:each>
```

See [Enumerable#chunk_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while), which made its debut in Ruby v.2.3.

This enumerator will generate the following elements to be passed to [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

```
e0.to_a
  #=> [[{:name=>"1", :address=>"USA",
  #      :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB"}],
  #    [{:name=>"5", :address=>"UK",
  #      :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"BC"},
  #     {:name=>"6", :address=>"CANADA",
  #      :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"CD"}],
  #    [{:name=>"29", :address=>"GERMANY",
  #      :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"], :sequence=>"DE"},
  #     {:name=>"30", :address=>"CHINA",
  #      :collection=>["LAPTOP", "SHIP", "MOUNTAIN"], :sequence=>"FG"}]
  #   ] 

e0.flat_map { |a| a.chunk { |g| g[:collection] }.map { |_,b| combine(b) } }
```

returns the array of hashes obtained in the example. Consider the first element generated by `e0` and passed to the block, and assigned to the block variable, by `flat_map`.

```
a = e0.next
  #=> [{:name=>"1", :address=>"USA",
  #     :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB"}]
```

The block calculation is therefore

```
e1 = a.chunk { |g| g[:collection] }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fa25c857158>:each> 
e1.to_a
  #=> [[["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"],
  #     [{:name=>"1", :address=>"USA",
  #       :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB"}]
  #    ]
  #   ] 

_c,b = e1.next
  #=> [["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"],
  #    [{:name=>"1", :address=>"USA",
  #      :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB"}]
  #   ] 
  # _c
  #   #=> ["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"] 
  # b #=> [{:name=>"1", :address=>"USA",
  #         :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB"}] 
combine(b)
  #=> {:name=>"1", :address=>"USA",
  #    :collection=>["LAND", "WATER", "OIL", "TREE", "SAND"], :sequence=>"AB"}
```

The remaining calculations are similar.